# How to paginate in Laravel when using Modell::find(array())

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-pagination

I'm grabbing some data in Laravel using the `find` method and only grabbing the id's I want:

`$my_ids = array(1,4,5,10);
$results = Model::find($my_ids);`

However, if I try to paginate via `Model::find($my_ids)->paginate(10)`, it throws the error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate()`.

How can I query to only get specific model Id's back from the database while also using pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest use the [eloquent query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects):

```
$results = Model::whereIn('id', $my_ids)->paginate(10);
```

Comment: That's eerie you posted nearly the exact same answer as I just did :)

Comment: heheh, well... was the obvius answer just only a few seconds after.  ;)

Answer (score 5):

Turns out I can use this syntax:

`$results = Model::whereIn('id', $my_ids)->paginate(10);`